# Polygons with convergent area

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

### Suppose that there is an equilateral triangle of area 10, call this $A_0$, we then trisect each side of this triangle, then cut off the corners, giving the polygon $A_1$, what is the area of this polygon, we then do this again to get $A_2$ (trisect sides, and cut corners), what is the area of this polygon? What is the area of $A_\infty$.

With this problem, I initially tried to generalise side length for $A_n$, then used the area of a polygon formula to find the area, I was wondering if anyone could come up with any other ideas, or alternatively do it the same way I did, to compare answers. Best of luck!

Comment: You have continuously asked this very question HERE, I believe 3 times in a row---->https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665051/convergent-area?noredirect=1#comment5504953_2665051

Comment: With different accounts, not to mention.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for $A_n$ as n goes to infinity is $0$

Note that 
$$A_0 = 10$$

$$A_1 = 10(2/3)$$
$$A_2= 10(2/3)^2$$
$$A_3= 10(2/3)^3$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$
$$A_n= 10(2/3)^{n}$$
$$ A_{\infty } =lim _{n\to \infty} 10(2/3)^n = 0 $$

Comment: So you are not cutting away all the corners of the new triangles each time? My answer was based on my assumption that you do the cutting on remaining little triangles as you did with the original one.

Comment: Yes that was the idea